# Multithreading Helper Classes in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

There are helper classes for implementing asynchronous tasks in Androids.

So far I've heard of two:

1. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Helps to do short tasks and notifies the UI about progress.
2. [SafeAsyncTask](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/9a9a6e4d807c8a5fcf5e05d1f865dadffc5b9405/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/util/SafeAsyncTask.java) from RoboGuice. Helps to do tasks within a ThreadPool, implementing the CallBack interface, this class also propagate exceptions.

Are there any more helper classes that I'm missing? Anything you would like to add on the above helper classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not exacly a helper class, but you can just use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). It is allways executed on the thread it was created in, it can be used to manage multithreading.

As a matter of fact, AsyncTask consists of a background thread and several handlers, these are called onPreExecute, onPostExecute and onProgressChanged, these are good for making changes on the UI thread from a background thread.